# getting content inside of all <span> using findall, only get the content that not has \n

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract the content that is inside the `span` tag under the structure:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">xxx</span>
```

I get a big html code from a web service and from there I extract the span tags with this structure.

the problem is that if the content of some span has a `\n` it does not extract it.

for example:

```
print(re.findall(pattern, '<span style="font-weight:bold">AAA\n</span><span style="font-weight:bold">ooo</span>'))
>>[ooo]
#output desired should be [AAA,ooo]
```

how can I fix this so that the content of the span is extracted if it has or does not have `\n`?

Comment: This question is TOTALLY dependent on your definition of 'pattern', but you haven't shown us that.  Show us what pattern you're using, and maybe we can help you.

Comment: I bet that the problem you are having is that some part of your pattern is too "greedy".  It's sucking up too much stuff, and is therefore sucking up all of the text up to and before 'ooo'. That is why it isn't matching both AAA and ooo.  Again, show us the expression.  I bet I can tell you right away what is wrong with your expression.

Comment: ...and why do you show the same example twice?  Am I missing something?  Those two sets of lines seem identical to me.

Comment: I honestly don't know how many times you need to be told not to use regex to parse HTML?

Comment: @akent, that's a naive and condescending statement.  Maybe the OP wants to understand how regular expressions work.  And I disagree that it's this clear that he should not be using a regex for what he wants to do.  A regex could be a perfectly acceptable solution here.  That's up to him to decide, not you.

Comment: @steve Check this user's previous questions today and tell me if you change your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup to handle element in html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h = """<span style="font-weight:bold">xxx</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
spans = soup.find_all("span")
for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

OUTPUT

```
u'xxx'
```

Comment: This, for two reasons, doesn't address the OPs question.  I can't believe this got two upvotes.  This answer is WRONG.  1) the OP didn't ask for a better way to do something.  He's asking about the use of regular expressions to solve a problem.  This doesn't address that, and 2) The sample code in this answer doesn't duplicate or address the problem he's having.  If this were his sample data, he'd be getting behavior he expects out of the code he already has.  The question involves HIS data.  You should at least show HIS data.

Comment: but I need find all the ocurrences. for example <span style="font-weight:bold">111</span><span style="font-weight:bold">222</span>  result: [111,222] Are there any way to do it?

Comment: yes, span = soup.find_all("span"). It will be a list, then iterate

Comment: @unusuario, do you want to move on to using another method, or do you want to understand why your regular expression isn't working?  You have to decide.  BeautifulSoup IS a better way to go, and YES, it will solve your problem. - but you could also fix your regular expression to do what you want it to do here.

Comment: @Steve I give answer for the problem of the OP and he likes it. Pls undo your negative vote

Comment: ...actually, 3 reasons this is a bad answer.  This code will find ALL span tags.  His regular expression might very well be looking specifically for particular spans.

Comment: @Wonka, who says that he liked it?  You posted your answer, and then he stated in a comment that it didn't do what he wanted it to do!  Someone upvoted your answer, but I'm guessing that it wasn't him.

Comment: I solved with             soup = BeautifulSoup(respuestaLemma,features="lxml")
            spans = soup.find_all("span",attrs={'style':"font-weight:bold"})
            aLemma=[]
            for idx,span in enumerate(spans):
                aLemma.append(spans[idx].text)